# System.Diagnostics.EventLog.dll assembly not on machine and .NET Framework is installed

Tags: c#, .net

According to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) the `System.Diagnostics.EventLog` class is part of the .NET Framework and it is defined in the `System.Diagnostics.EventLog.DLL` assembly.

I do have .NET Framework 4.8 installed on my machine and I expected my app to be able to bind to this referenced assembly at runtime without needing to provide the assembly with my installation. However, it is failing to bind to it due to file not found (referring to the assembly itself). I.e. the assembly is not in one of the locations the runtime is looking. I am using fuslogvw.exe to see this information.

I have manually searched for this assembly on my machine and it is not in the GAC and it is not in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319.

Since it is supposed to be part of the .NET Framework, I am unclear why it is not on the machine.

I should note it is the installer itself that is needing to bind to the EventLog assembly. (a wix installer using a custom action that ends up referencing EventLog).

I suppose my question is: why is it not on the machine if it is part of the .NET Framework? Or maybe I am looking in the wrong location, where will I find it?

Any insight that can be provided is appreciated.

**Edit:**

The FirstLib that references the EventLog class targets .NET Standard 2.0. SecondLib references FirstLib and it targets .NET Framework 4.8.

With .NET Standard the `EventLog` class is in the assembly     `System.Diagnostics.EventLog.dll`. With .NET Framework 4.8 it is in `System.dll` assembly. I believe this may be the cause of the problem and I need to tell it to look in System.dll instead.

I am not sure what the solution is but Hans comment made me realize I got part of the original description wrong.

Comment: Selection the `Version` in the web page at the upper left.  Like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog?view=netframework-4.8), now you see it is in System.dll.  It got special treatment in .NETCore because it can't work on Unix operating systems.

Comment: @HansPassant Ah this does help as it brought closer to my attention that the library that is actually references the EventLog class is in a .NET Standard 2.0 lib.

Comment: @HansPassant I hit enter before I intended to on that previous comment. What we have is a WIX project that references an MSI installer project that then references a .NET Framework 4.8 project (custom actions) that references a .NET Standard 2.0 project that is the one who uses EventLog. I believe this explains why just having .NET Framework 4.8 on the machine is not enough, although I am not quite sure of the solution yet. I believe I need to look at assembly binding redirects. I will report back.

Comment: After reading up on assembly binding redirects I see that is for versions only, not going from assembly A.dll to assembly B.dll. Looking at @CodeCasters Answer and I believe is promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have:

- A NET Framework 4.8 project, referencing

  - A .NET Standard 2.0 library, referencing

    - System.Diagnostics.EventLog from the Windows Extensions

Then your framework project also needs that EventLog DLL. When targeting Framework (and therefore implicitly Windows), this will result in a "shim" DLL to be deployed next to your application. This will have its types forwarded to the appropriate Framework DLLs.

Comment: Looking... this is how we do it in our actual app.... this is for a wix installer exe but it should be the same. Will report back.

Comment: As you suggested, I added the System.Diagnostics.EventLog nuget package reference to the .NET Framework 4.8 project and this fixed the problem. I understand now why it is necessary to have it on both now too. Thank you, CodeCaster and everyone who helped.